# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Hey i need a hand this is my first post on here so i don't know how to do this but i would like to find out how to fix my issue i am new to coding

```
def get_audio():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = listener.listen(source)
        said =''

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception' + str(e))
Wake = 'hey friday'
while True:
text = get_audio()
    if text.count(Wake) < 0:
        talk('I am ready sir')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score -1):

Your `get_audio` function must return something.

`text` gets nothing from `get_audio` so it emits AttributeError.